# Arrastrar y soltar en un modal en quasar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

estoy trabajando en un proyecto con vue js en quasar y me gustaría saber si hay alguna posibilidad de que un modal (q-dialog) se pueda arrastrar y soltar, qué plugin o función me permitiría hacer eso ya que la verdad no sé como hacerlo, si alguien sabe como hacerlo o tiene algún ejemplo se los agradecería mucho